# Some attribute values aren't case sensitive (input[type]) some are (*[class]) - how does Html Agility Pack handle that?

Tags: html-agility-pack

I am trying to select an element by its type

```
//input[(@type = 'checkbox' or @type = 'radio') and @name = 'BigBobMcNob']
```

but its not matching, because my type is capitalised

```
<input type='Checkbox' name='BigBobMcNob' />
```

How do I fix that? and if I do will it break when selecting on class, which should be case sensitive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just iterate through the node collection and check each node against your conditions like this:

```
var allowedName = "Checkbox";
var allowedTypes = new[] { "checkbox", "radio" };
var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.DescendantNodes()
    .Where(n =>
        n.Name == "input" &&
        allowedTypes.Contains(n.GetAttributeValue("type", null), StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) &&
        n.GetAttributeValue("type", null) == allowedName
    ).ToList();
```

For `type` attribute comparison, [`StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparer.ordinalignorecase.aspx) comparer is used; `name` attribute doesn't require a special comparer.

Comment: Thanks alex, the problem here is that we are configuring selectors with xpath strings through a UI, I could use dynamic linq, but its all getting a bit too complex :(